# Fetch only 5 records of each Id which is pass in $in In MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, fetch

I have a query in MongoDb where I am fetching records from some collection using `$in` where I am passing an array. The query is like this

```
db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id" : {"$in" : [3,5,8,64,23,18,78,67]}});
```

As this query is working perfectly fine. **It will fetch all the records of these ids but I only wants to fetch only 5 record for each Id like 5 records for Id 3, 5 records for Id 8,5 records for Id 64 and so on for every id.**

I have even tried with `$last` but no success so far .

```
db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id" : {"$in" : [3,5,8,64,23,18,78,67],"$last" : 5}});
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg updated my Question.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia - To get 5 records for each Id, we can do it thru aggregation pipeline. Please see the list of operators in aggregation pipeline -
 https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Thanks for reference but I am not able to identify which one I need to use and how as there is no example for it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach using aggregation pipeline is shown below

Let us have documents like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f1"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f2"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f3"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f4"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f5"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f6"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f7"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f8"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f9"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9fa"), "myId" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fb"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fc"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fd"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fe"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9ff"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1ea00"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1ea01"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1ea02"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1ea03"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1ea04"), "myId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea05"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea06"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea07"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea08"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea09"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea0a"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea0b"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea0c"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea0d"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795018e947e4f4c1ea0e"), "myId" : 103 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea19"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1a"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1b"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1c"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1d"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1e"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea1f"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea20"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea21"), "myId" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a795e18e947e4f4c1ea22"), "myId" : 45 }
```

The above shown sample collection has four different id's 3,5,45 and 103

Let us pick 5 records from id's 3 and 5

```
db.getCollection('feed').aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "result1": [
                {$match:{ myId:3}},
                {$limit: 5}
            ],
            "result2": [
                {$match: {"myId": 5}},
                {$limit: 5}
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {$project : { result: {$concatArrays:["$result1", "$result2"]}} },
    {$unwind:"$result"} 
])
```

After execution of this query we will be getting a result as shown below

```
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fb"), "myId" : 3 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fc"), "myId" : 3 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fd"), "myId" : 3 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9fe"), "myId" : 3 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a794918e947e4f4c1e9ff"), "myId" : 3 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f1"), "myId" : 5 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f2"), "myId" : 5 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f3"), "myId" : 5 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f4"), "myId" : 5 } }
{ "result" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a793118e947e4f4c1e9f5"), "myId" : 5 } }
```

In this approach we have used [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Really Great !!